# Probability and Statistics: Determine possible parameter value

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable from the normal distribution with mean $11$ and standard deviation of $3$.

Determine a possible value of parameter $a$ such that

$$ 0.940 \lt P(a \lt X \lt 3a) \lt 0.941 $$

Answer (score 1):

Convert to standard N(0, 1) by using

$$Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$$

then use a table. This leaves us with $$0.940 < \mathbb{P}(\frac{a - 11}{3} < Z < \frac{3a - 11}{3}) < 0.941$$

Looking at our standard normal table (looking for values approximately 2$\sigma$ away), we notice

$$\mathbb{P}(-1.76 < Z < 2.05) \approx 0.9405$$

Solving for $a$, we have $$a = 2.05 + \frac{11}{3} \approx 5.716 $$